# Change dotted lines to straight lines

Tags: thesis, addlines

I have a template of the title page that I was trying to change and make it work. It works, but in the title page, I would like to change the dotted lines to straight lines in the following three places..

Any ideas? I found this style online and it was already there. I could not change it to the straight lines..

The code is provided as well:

```
 %\hbox to \hsize{\hfill\hbox to 3in{\leaders\hbox to 1em{.\hss}\hfill}}
 %\smallskip 
 %\hbox to \hsize{\hfill\hbox to 3in{{\@supervisor} (Supervisor)\hfill}}
 %\bigskip
 %\hbox to \hsize{\hfill\hbox to 3in{\leaders\hbox to 1em{.\hss}\hfill}}
 %\smallskip 
 %%%\hbox to \hsize{\hfill\hbox to 3in{{\@external} (External)\hfill}}
 %\hbox to \hsize{\hfill\hbox to 3in{{\@external}\hfill}}
 %\bigskip
 \@for\@examer:=\@examiners\do{
 \hbox to \hsize{\hfill\hbox to 3in{\leaders\hbox to 1em{.\hss}\hfill}}
 \smallskip 
 \hbox to \hsize{\hfill\hbox to 3in{{\@examer}\hfill}}
 %% \hbox to \hsize{\hfill\hbox to 3in{{\@examer} (Examiner)\hfill}}
 \bigskip
 }
 %\bigskip
 %\hbox to \hsize{\hfill\hbox to 3in{{\@chair} (Chair)\hfill}}
 \vfill

 \noindent
 {\bf Date}: \hbox to 1.5in{\leaders\hbox to 1em{\hss.\hss}\hfill}
```

UPDATE:

I have figured the lines out, but now is there a way for me to put a word: (SUPERVISOR) under the Chilled Prof1?

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

Here is my code:

```
\@for\@examer:=\@examiners\do{
    \hbox to \hsize{\hfill \hbox to 18pc{\hrulefill}}
    \smallskip 
    \hbox to \hsize{\hfill\hbox to 3in{{\@examer}\hfill}}
%%  \hbox to \hsize{\hfill\hbox to 3in{{\@examer} (Examiner)\hfill}}
    \bigskip
}
%\bigskip
%\hbox to \hsize{\hfill\hbox to 3in{{\@chair} (Chair)\hrulefill}}
\vfill

\noindent
{\bf Date}: \hbox to 15pc{\hrulefill}
```

This code above gives me this:

[[image]

And now how can I add that single line with the word Supervisor under the first Chilled Prof1?:)

Comment: Are you looking for this?  

Date: `\hrulefill`
OR
Date: `\hbox to 5pc{\hrulefill}`

Comment: The template seems to be obsolete and shouldn't be used anymore.

Answer (score 1):

As example using the [dashrule package](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/dashrule) :

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{dashrule}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\parindent=0pt
\parskip=3mm


{\bf Date }: \hdashrule{2cm}{1pt}{1pt}

{\bf Date }: \hdashrule{\fill}{4pt}{5pt}

{\bf Date }: \hdashrule{\fill}{1pt}{1pt}

{\bf Date }: \hrulefill % <---- Don't need dashrule package 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Everytime when I tried to replace all hfill with hrulefill it either goes to some random places that I do not want to or just did not want to change.

Comment: please show the code

Comment: please see code above in the updated question.