# How to recreate the dotted line from the ToC?

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

Is there a command to draw a dotted line like the one in the table of contents?
I used `\dotfill` but this creates a row with a different spacing between the dots.

[image]

The dotted lines on top were created using

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item[3.1] Verfügbarkeit\enspace\dotfill\enspace 7
    \item[3.1] Verfügbarkeiit\enspace\dotfill\enspace 7
\end{itemize}
```

Here you can see that the dots of "Verfügbarkeiit" are not exactly below the ones from "Verfügbarkeit"

The ones below are the line of the ToC.

How can I achieve the same line?
Especially the fact that all dots are below each other (in a straight column)

Thanks!

Comment: hi ! refere to : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298073/change-dotted-lines-to-straight-lines/298083#298083

Comment: But with the dashrule package it is not possible to vertically align all dots to each other. right?

Comment: What do you want exactly ? Could you show us a picture ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy answer would be to just use `\contentsline`, since you probably want to copy the look of the other "list of *x*"es:

```
\contentsline{figure}{\numberline{3.2.1}Verfügbarkeit}{x}
```

The first parameter would be the entry type you want it to look like, for example `section` or `chapter`.

However, you could also [automate the creation of your custom list of ...](http://texblog.org/2008/07/13/define-your-own-list-of/), which may be more maintainable in the long run.

One can also dig down into the definitons of the macros to find the magic that happens inside:

```
\show\contentsline
% results in #1->\csname l@#1\endcsname
```

So we see that the first parameter is used to complete a macro name, so let's see how this one expands:

```
\makeatletter
\show\l@figure
% results in ->\@dottedtocline {1}{1.5em}{2.3em}
```

Getting closer...

```
\show\@dottedtocline
% results in #1#2#3#4#5->\ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else \vskip \z@ \@plus .2\p@ {\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip \parindent #2\relax \@afterindenttrue \interlinepenalty \@M \leavevmode \@tempdima #3\relax \advance \leftskip \@tempdima \null \nobreak \hskip -\leftskip {#4}\nobreak \leaders \hbox {$\m@th \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox {.}\mkern \@dotsep mu$}\hfill \nobreak \hb@xt@ \@pnumwidth {\hfil \normalfont \normalcolor #5}\par }\fi
```

Ok, this is getting messy. But knowing that `\leaders` is responsible, we can isolate the interesting part of this command:

```
\leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern\@dotsepmu\hbox{.}\mkern\@dotsepmu$}\hfill
```

So if you want just the lines, but want them to look exactly like the tableofcontents ones, you could wrap this into a macro.

Comment: I tried your first example, but it won't work. I changed it to `\contentsline{section}{\numberline{3.2.1}Verfügbarkeit}{7}{equation.3.2.1}` and it worked. I'll try your second part of the answer soon.

Comment: Apparently, the number of arguments depends on whether `hyperref` is loaded and possibly on the document class. An automated method would definitely be best.

Comment: Second part also works, but the automation from the Link is not suitable for me. Nevertheless nice Answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can set a new command that uses the same value of the ToC.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\newcommand\mydotfill{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{itemize}
    \item[3.1] label\enspace\mydotfill\enspace 7
    \item[3.1] long label\enspace\mydotfill\enspace 7
    \item[3.1] very long label\enspace\mydotfill\enspace 7
\end{itemize}
\vspace{3cm}
\section{Verfügbarkeit}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your dots aren't in a vertical row. The are shifted a little bit. I like to have  each dot arranged exactly below the one above.

Comment: @Phil Why should they? One is a ToC entry, the other is an `itemize` entry. They aren't probably going to be in the same page anyways. Or do you want to enter custom entries in the ToC?

Comment: Soon I'll have more equations with different lengths of their names. I want to align all dots of the "list of equations" exactly among each other. I'll add a picture to my post.

Comment: haven't tested this, but ... the first line is bold, and the second isn't.  what happens if the leaders are forced into `\mdseries`?

Comment: @Phil As far as the itemize is concerned, adding longer labels is not an issue. See edit.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Are you thinking that might be the reason for the misalignment?

Comment: OK, that was my fault. It works, but @wrtlprnft's is shorter and more suitable to my usecase. Thanks!

Comment: @Phil What are the numbers in the item supposed to mean? I'm referring to `3.1` or `3.2.1`.

Comment: This is the number of the equation. I accidentally copied `3.2.1` but I ment `3.1`. In this example it's just a placeholder. I referenced it with `\ref{eq:test}`. I also created a macro but to make things easier I just copied the inner macro syntax

Comment: @Alenanno -- that's exactly what i'm thinking.  cm bold has a wider em than cm regular.