# Draw colored dash line in table

Tags: tables, hhline

I am trying to draw colored dash lines in table.
Here is the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{dashrule}
\usepackage{ehhline}

\newcommand{\mycdl}[4]{\leaders\hbox{\textcolor{#1}{\hdashrule[0ex][c]{#3}{#2}{#4}}}\hfil}
\newcommand\dasheda[1]{\mycdl{#1}{\arrayrulewidth}{15pt}{1.5pt 3pt 6pt 3pt 1.5pt 0pt}}
\newcommand\dashedb[1]{\mycdl{#1}{\arrayrulewidth}{15pt}{3pt 3pt 3pt 3pt 3pt 0pt}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{!{\vrule width 1pt}p{2cm}!{\vrule width 1pt}}
\hhline{!{\dasheda{red}}} \\
\hhline{!{\dashedb{red}}} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The dash line can not reach the right border.

I find a question related to this:[Change dotted lines to straight lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298073/change-dotted-lines-to-straight-lines/298083#298083). But I don't know how to make it with the method in this answer.

Comment: Try to use `\xleaders` primitive instead `\leaders`.

Comment: @wipet xleaders spread excess space equally between the boxes, which means an integrated line is also broken.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean "integrated line". In fact, you have repeated box in the shape "- - -- " and this box does not pass to the rest of the space. What to do? A) leave empty space: use `\leaders`, B) leave empty space divided to the same amount to left and right: use `\cleaders`, C) leave empty space divided to the same amount left, right and between boxes, use `\xleades`. There is no more TeX primitives for this case. If you need something more special, say it explicitly. We can do a linear transformation or cropping path or something else. But not by classical TeX primitives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following trick:

```
\input opmac

\localcolor
\def\rul#1{\vrule height.5pt width#1pt}
\def\ker#1{\kern#1pt}
\def\dashbox{\hbox to15pt{\rul3\ker3\rul6\hfil}}
\def\reddashrule{\Red\leaders\dashbox\hfil\kern-15pt\White\vrule width15pt\kern-15pt}

\vbox{\offinterlineskip
\hbox to2cm{\reddashrule}
\hbox to2cm{\strut\vrule width1pt \hfil \vrule width1pt}
\hbox to2cm{\reddashrule}
}

\bye
```

[image: red dashed]

The idea is to use the `\leaders` by 15pt longer than you explicitly need because the repeated box is 15 pt width. Then we are sure that the dashed line is drawn at least to the end of the box boundary, but it can overlap. So, we return by `\kern-15pt`, draw the line 15pt in white color (it erases the overlapping line) and finally we return back by second `\kern-15pt`.

I re-coded our example to plain TeX (using OPmac for colors) because I don't use LaTeX. If you are using LaTeX then you can re-code this idea to LaTeX without problems.

Comment: How can I get the width of the entry of the alignment if I do not specify the width for it

Comment: @ZhiyuanLck Your `{tabular}` (in your LaTeX code) has specified fixed width: 1pt from `\vrule` 2cm prom `p` and 1pt from `\vrule`. The total width of your `{tabular}` is 2cm+2pt. The `\hhline` in your `{tabular}` does `\hbox to2cm+2pt{\leaders...\hfil}` from TeX primitive point of view. It means that the width is specified. I emulated almost the same width in my code (but without +2pt for sake of simplicity). And the mentioned macro does not need to know the explicit width of alignment.

Comment: Yes I specify the width by `p`, I mean if it is `c`, is it possible to get the width

Comment: This question does not correspond to your first question about dash lines in any way. What about `c` columns: The `\halign` primitive (for tables) does two passes over its data. In the first pass, the macros inside items are expanded and boxes for each item are created. Then `\halign` measures most wide box in each column (i.e. column width) and does second pass: each box is recalculated to box to column width. In this pass no macros are processed. You cannot measure simply the column widths. by macros. But you can measure the width of whole table: `\setbox0=\vbox{\halign{...}}\the\wd0`.

Comment: Thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 2):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` and its built-in command `\Hline`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|w{c}{2cm}|}
\Hline[tikz={dashed,red}] 
\\
\Hline[tikz={dashed,red}] 
\\
\Hline[tikz={dashed,red}] 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]